# Is it ever useful to SELECT DISTINCT on the primary key column(s)?

Tags: select, primary-key, distinct

From my understanding, primary keys are unique by definition. If that's true, would one ever want to SELECT DISTINCT on the primary key? Is this ever practical/useful?

Comment: Yes it is unique for the record so without joining to other tables, `DISTINCT` wouldn't matter. However, in a one to many relationship, or when joining to a table with unnormalized data, it may be beneficial.

Comment: You don't have to use DISTINCT in a PRIMARY KEY columns since its already UNIQUE. There is also a performance impact when using DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you join with another m:n table that duplicates the PK value in your result set, then it would be useful.

Comment: (Or 1:n for that matter)

Comment: Note that *multi*-column distinct groups are more efficiently queried using the [GROUP BY](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct) clause.